# Animated SVG logo using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the below mentioned codes for animating SVG logo, but it seems JS code didn't work for animation. where is the error? Although I have copied the same codes pasted at the link: https://codepen.io/ksenia-k/pen/bmMoVr

The logo is not animated as per the code stated at the link of pen code above.

```js
let wingsTl;

initWings();
wingsTl.play();

function initWings() {
    // SVG shapes
    const rightWingFrames = [
        'M1005 1201c-8,-399 7,-538 217,-746 0,0 -9,53 -65,116 -10,7 -21,13 13,-7 -38,61 -67,127 -67,127 24,-42 31,-47 48,-69 -64,125 -69,145 -93,205 16,-21 9,-22 33,-49 -61,152 -51,137 -86,423z',
        'M1005 1202c306,-365 394,-363 549,-523 31,-45 -38,116 -102,137 -10,3 -23,0 28,12 -37,37 -89,46 -89,46 24,12 24,6 53,17 -106,50 -100,54 -188,83 4,16 -12,-4 22,12 -94,52 -136,69 -273,216z',
        'M1008 1200c-98,-290 418,-453 655,-419 0,0 -25,87 -159,82 -12,0 56,32 101,13 -76,71 -181,8 -181,8 0,0 6,37 108,54 -129,68 -263,-8 -263,-8 0,0 -6,21 51,42 -322,2 -312,228 -312,228z',
        'M1005 1199c-206,-226 201,-583 431,-647 0,0 12,89 -112,139 -11,5 64,7 98,-29 -41,96 -163,80 -163,80 0,0 20,31 121,6 -91,115 -244,99 -244,99 0,0 2,21 63,18 -294,131 -194,334 -194,334z'
    ];
    const leftWingFrames = [
        'M1009 1201c8,-399 -7,-538 -217,-746 0,0 10,53 66,116 9,7 20,13 -13,-7 37,61 67,127 67,127 -25,-42 -32,-47 -49,-69 64,125 69,145 93,205 -16,-21 -9,-22 -33,-49 61,152 51,137 86,423z',
        'M1009 1202c-306,-365 -393,-363 -548,-523 -32,-45 38,116 101,137 10,3 23,0 -28,12 37,37 89,46 89,46 -24,12 -24,6 -52,17 106,50 99,54 187,83 -4,16 12,-4 -21,12 93,52 136,69 272,216z',
        'M1006 1200c98,-290 -418,-453 -654,-419 0,0 24,87 158,82 12,0 -56,32 -101,13 76,71 181,8 181,8 0,0 -6,37 -108,54 129,68 263,-8 263,-8 0,0 7,21 -51,42 322,2 312,228 312,228z',
        'M996 1202c207,-226 -201,-583 -430,-647 0,0 -13,89 111,139 11,4 -63,6 -97,-29 41,96 163,80 163,80 0,0 -21,31 -121,6 90,114 244,99 244,99 0,0 -2,21 -64,18 295,131 194,334 194,334z'
    ];
    const numberOfFrames = 4;

    // animation speed parameter
    const frameTime = 0.13;

    // selectors
    const rightWing = document.getElementsByClassName('wing-right')[0];
    const leftWing = document.getElementsByClassName('wing-left')[0];

    // timeline
    wingsTl = gsap.timeline({
        repeat: -1,
        repeatDelay: 0.5,
        paused: true
    });
    // 1st flap
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++) {
        // make 1st frame longer and w/ ease
        let ease = (i === 0) ? 'power1.in' : 'none';
        let timeExt = (i === 0) ? 1.5 : 1;
        wingsTl
            .to(rightWing, {
                duration: frameTime * timeExt,
                attr: { d: rightWingFrames[i] },
                ease: ease
            })
            .to(leftWing, {
                duration: frameTime * timeExt,
                attr: { d: leftWingFrames[i] },
                ease: ease
            }, '-=' + (frameTime * timeExt));
    }
    // 2nd flap
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++) {
        // make last frame longer and w/ ease
        let ease = (i === (numberOfFrames - 1)) ? 'power1.out' : 'none';
        let timeExt = (i === (numberOfFrames - 1)) ? 2 : 1;
        wingsTl
            .to(rightWing, {
                duration: frameTime * timeExt,
                attr: { d: rightWingFrames[i] },
                ease: ease
            })
            .to(leftWing, {
                duration: frameTime * timeExt,
                attr: { d: leftWingFrames[i] },
                ease: ease
            }, '-=' + (frameTime * timeExt));
    }
}
```

```css
/* 
    Logo: CSS below has anything to do with animation,
    it's defines elements size and position on the page 
*/

body {
background-color: black;}
svg {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  position: fixed;

  z-index: 1;
}

/*End logo*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Imagin-It </title>

    <!-- stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <!-- google fonts -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!-- icons -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>

    <!-- gsap -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

    <!-- AnimeJS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
<!--JQueryAhmed-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--whatsupJquery-->
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!--Floating WhatsApp css-->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://rawcdn.githack.com/rafaelbotazini/floating-whatsapp/3d18b26d5c7d430a1ab0b664f8ca6b69014aed68/floating-wpp.min.css"
    />
    <!--Floating WhatsApp javascript-->
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/rafaelbotazini/floating-whatsapp/3d18b26d5c7d430a1ab0b664f8ca6b69014aed68/floating-wpp.min.js"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    


     <!--Logo-->
     <svg viewBox="-700 450 2700 900" >
      <g>
          <path fill="#fff" class="wing-right" opacity="1" d="M1005 1199c-206,-226 201,-583 431,-647 0,0 12,89 -112,139 -11,5 64,7 98,-29 -41,96 -163,80 -163,80 0,0 20,31 121,6 -91,115 -244,99 -244,99 0,0 2,21 63,18 -294,131 -194,334 -194,334z"/>
          <path fill="#6adb9d" class="wing-left" opacity="1" d="M996 1202c207,-226 -201,-583 -430,-647 0,0 -13,89 111,139 11,4 -63,6 -97,-29 41,96 163,80 163,80 0,0 -21,31 -121,6 90,114 244,99 244,99 0,0 -2,21 -64,18 295,131 194,334 194,334z"/>
      </g>
      <g font-size="350" >
          <text fill="#fff" x="900" y="1250" font-weight="600" text-anchor="end" >Imagine</text>
          <text fill="#6adb9d" font-weight="800" x="1080" y="1250" text-anchor="start" >It</text>
      </g>
  </svg>

  <!--End Logo-->
  
    
    <!-- js -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let wingsTl;

initWings();
wingsTl.play();

function initWings() {
    // SVG shapes
    const rightWingFrames = [
        'M1005 1201c-8,-399 7,-538 217,-746 0,0 -9,53 -65,116 -10,7 -21,13 13,-7 -38,61 -67,127 -67,127 24,-42 31,-47 48,-69 -64,125 -69,145 -93,205 16,-21 9,-22 33,-49 -61,152 -51,137 -86,423z',
        'M1005 1202c306,-365 394,-363 549,-523 31,-45 -38,116 -102,137 -10,3 -23,0 28,12 -37,37 -89,46 -89,46 24,12 24,6 53,17 -106,50 -100,54 -188,83 4,16 -12,-4 22,12 -94,52 -136,69 -273,216z',
        'M1008 1200c-98,-290 418,-453 655,-419 0,0 -25,87 -159,82 -12,0 56,32 101,13 -76,71 -181,8 -181,8 0,0 6,37 108,54 -129,68 -263,-8 -263,-8 0,0 -6,21 51,42 -322,2 -312,228 -312,228z',
        'M1005 1199c-206,-226 201,-583 431,-647 0,0 12,89 -112,139 -11,5 64,7 98,-29 -41,96 -163,80 -163,80 0,0 20,31 121,6 -91,115 -244,99 -244,99 0,0 2,21 63,18 -294,131 -194,334 -194,334z'
    ];
    const leftWingFrames = [
        'M1009 1201c8,-399 -7,-538 -217,-746 0,0 10,53 66,116 9,7 20,13 -13,-7 37,61 67,127 67,127 -25,-42 -32,-47 -49,-69 64,125 69,145 93,205 -16,-21 -9,-22 -33,-49 61,152 51,137 86,423z',
        'M1009 1202c-306,-365 -393,-363 -548,-523 -32,-45 38,116 101,137 10,3 23,0 -28,12 37,37 89,46 89,46 -24,12 -24,6 -52,17 106,50 99,54 187,83 -4,16 12,-4 -21,12 93,52 136,69 272,216z',
        'M1006 1200c98,-290 -418,-453 -654,-419 0,0 24,87 158,82 12,0 -56,32 -101,13 76,71 181,8 181,8 0,0 -6,37 -108,54 129,68 263,-8 263,-8 0,0 7,21 -51,42 322,2 312,228 312,228z',
        'M996 1202c207,-226 -201,-583 -430,-647 0,0 -13,89 111,139 11,4 -63,6 -97,-29 41,96 163,80 163,80 0,0 -21,31 -121,6 90,114 244,99 244,99 0,0 -2,21 -64,18 295,131 194,334 194,334z'
    ];
    const numberOfFrames = 4;

    // animation speed parameter
    const frameTime = 0.13;

    // selectors
    const rightWing = document.getElementsByClassName('wing-right')[0];
    const leftWing = document.getElementsByClassName('wing-left')[0];

    // timeline
    wingsTl = gsap.timeline({
        repeat: -1,
        repeatDelay: 0.5,
        paused: true
    });
    // 1st flap
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++) {
        // make 1st frame longer and w/ ease
        let ease = (i === 0) ? 'power1.in' : 'none';
        let timeExt = (i === 0) ? 1.5 : 1;
        wingsTl
            .to(rightWing, {
                duration: frameTime * timeExt,
                attr: { d: rightWingFrames[i] },
                ease: ease
            })
            .to(leftWing, {
                duration: frameTime * timeExt,
                attr: { d: leftWingFrames[i] },
                ease: ease
            }, '-=' + (frameTime * timeExt));
    }
    // 2nd flap
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++) {
        // make last frame longer and w/ ease
        let ease = (i === (numberOfFrames - 1)) ? 'power1.out' : 'none';
        let timeExt = (i === (numberOfFrames - 1)) ? 2 : 1;
        wingsTl
            .to(rightWing, {
                duration: frameTime * timeExt,
                attr: { d: rightWingFrames[i] },
                ease: ease
            })
            .to(leftWing, {
                duration: frameTime * timeExt,
                attr: { d: leftWingFrames[i] },
                ease: ease
            }, '-=' + (frameTime * timeExt));
    }
}
```

```css
/* 
    CSS below has anything to do with animation,
    it's defines elements size and position on the page 
*/

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
svg {
    width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="-700 450 2700 900" >
    <g>
        <path fill="#aaa" class="wing-right" opacity="1" d="M1005 1199c-206,-226 201,-583 431,-647 0,0 12,89 -112,139 -11,5 64,7 98,-29 -41,96 -163,80 -163,80 0,0 20,31 121,6 -91,115 -244,99 -244,99 0,0 2,21 63,18 -294,131 -194,334 -194,334z"/>
        <path fill="#20686F" class="wing-left" opacity="1" d="M996 1202c207,-226 -201,-583 -430,-647 0,0 -13,89 111,139 11,4 -63,6 -97,-29 41,96 163,80 163,80 0,0 -21,31 -121,6 90,114 244,99 244,99 0,0 -2,21 -64,18 295,131 194,334 194,334z"/>
    </g>
    <g font-size="350" >
        <text fill="#aaa" x="900" y="1250" font-weight="600" text-anchor="end" >animated</text>
        <text fill="#20686F" font-weight="800" x="1080" y="1250" text-anchor="start" >logo</text>
    </g>
</svg>
//you not put above cdn , i hop it help you
```